# Google App Engine/ Custom Domain - Preferring https over http

Tags: node.js, reactjs, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, dns

I have an App Engine app deployed on Google's App Engine (flex) and it is mapped to a custom domain i.e. example.com. When i access the naked domain of example.com, i am led to http://example.com. However, there is an https://example.com up and running. The app is a react front end, node/express back end. Is there any way I can redirect all incoming requests to the https site or even remove the http version of the site?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the `secure` directive in `app.yaml`:

```
- url: /.*
  script: auto
  secure: always
```

Answer (score 0):

You should forward it in your domain panel.

```
1.Open your domain settings, find DNS or "forwarding" page.
2.Forward example.com to https://www.example.com or https://example.com
3.Choose "Permanent(301)
```

Thats all